# The correct way to create collection during mongoose transaction

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

How to autocreate collection during mongoose transaction if the collection was not created yet?

I'm aware of mongoose limitation that restricts user to create (or delete) mongoose collections during open transaction session.

Also, I was able to find 3 possible solutions on how to fix that:
1. [`autoCreate` option](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#autoCreate)
2. [`Model.init()` method](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.init)
3. [`Model.createCollection()` method](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.createCollection)

Which one to use? Without losing indexes etc.

app.models.ts

```
import { model, Schema } from 'mongoose';

const UserSchema = new Schema<UserDocument>({
  name: {
    type: Schema.Types.String,
    required: true,
  }
}); // { autoCreate: true } <-- ???

export const UserModel = model<UserDocument>('User', UserSchema);
```

app.ts

```
import { startSession } from 'mongoose';

import { UserModel } from './app.models.ts'; 


async function createUser() { 
  // await UserModel.createCollection(); ??
  // or 
  // await UserModel.init(); ??

  const session = await startSession();
  sesssion.startTransaction();

  try {
    const [user] = await UserModel.create([{ name: 'John' }], { session });

    await session.commitTransaction();

    return user;
  } catch (error) {
    await session.abortTransaction();
  } finally {
    session.endSession()
  }
}

foo();
```

Answer (score -1):

> If a collection does not exist, MongoDB creates the collection when you first store data for that collection. You can also explicitly create a collection with various options, such as setting the maximum size or the documentation validation rules.

Anyway, mongoose takes care of indexes, collection, etc...
you just need to define the collection name: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection

```
const UserSchema = new Schema<UserDocument>({
  name: {
    type: Schema.Types.String,
    required: true,
  }
}, {collection: 'users'});
```

There is the answer about transactions and collection creating -https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6699

Actually, I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/db-migrate package to create collections and indexes before starting an app.

Comment: The documentation says: `Set this option if you need a different name for your collection.`. I don't need a different name. I need to create a collection before transaction if it was not created yet.

Comment: I see, anyway as I mentioned above, the collection will be created by MongoDB. You don't need to create it

Comment: Are you sure that this approach will work with mongoose transactions?

Comment: nope it doesn't work. The error message is `Cannot create namespace test.filials in multi-document transaction.`

Comment: ok, I edited the answer. You can check db-migrate package and create collection and indexes before starting the app. The same approach as for SQL databases.